# Which model is better: One that overfits or one that underfits?

Tags: model, overfitting

From practical point of view, is it better to have a model that is overfitting the data or a model that is underfitting it?

Comment: Is it better to wear shoes that are too big, or too small?

Comment: @Tim I know what you want to say, but from practical point of view, it is better to wear shoes that are too big.

Comment: With models (as with shoes) it depends on what you're trying to do with them. This would affect the relative importance of bias and variance -- or whatever other measures of similar quantities would matter for your particular use. In some cases more bias is seen as better than more variance (indeed we often choose to do it deliberately by regularization),

Comment: Both terms are pejorative, so you don't want either. Classically, an underfit model is simpler and can usually be improved by looking at where it fits badly (not so well). An overfit model is often trickier to change because if you've estimated a cartload of parameters it can be very hard to know where best to start simplifying.

Answer (score 9):

Compare the two models on the plot below. First (red curve) heavily overfitts the data, while the second one (blue line) underfitts it. Can you tell which one is better? I'd say that both are bad.

[image: Two models]

If your model overfitts, then it perfectly fits your data, but can possibly be poor for making out-of-sample predictions. If it underfitts, then if poorly fits your in-sample data, but it can work better or worse on external data. Both cases are bad. From *practical* point of view you choose the model that best fits your purpose, or saying it in two words, *it depends*. From practical point of view you wouldn't be considering model that is poor.

Comment: Did you take a completely arbitrary blue line? Does not look like a regression line, for example.

Comment: @RichardHardy yes, this is completely arbitrary, completely made-up example.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say in general whether overfitting or underfitting is less desireable — this probably depends on your application.

In practice though, it's probably better to start with a model that has enough capacity to overfit your training data since there are lots of techniques for dealing with overfitting (e.g., regularization, dropout, dimensionality reduction, etc.)

Answer (score -2):

In ARIMA model over-fitting is often performed due to model mis-specifcation incorporating an unwarranted differencing operator and a self-cancelling ma operator leads to poor forecasts. Incorporating self-cancelling ARMA structure also has the same effect. In terms of incorporating statistically non-significant (unnecessary i.e. not different from 0.0) lag structures for causal variables generally has little or no effect. I suggest that over-modelling ARIMA models can be a bad idea while under-modelling casual models is a bad idea.